# Use Linq to get multiple MAX values in group clause

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query:

```
from x in CARS
from y in SHOWS
    .Where(y=>y.CARID == x.CARID)
group y.COLOR by x.CARS
into g
select new { CARID = g.Key, WINDOWS = g.Max()}
```

Resultant sql query in linqpad is this:

```
SELECT t0.CARID, MAX(t1.WINDOWS) agg1
FROM CARS t0
INNER JOIN SHOWS t1
  ON (t1.CARID = t0.CARID)
GROUP BY t0.CARID
```

How can I get another max value in Linq so that my sql looks like this:

```
SELECT t0.CARID, MAX(t1.WINDOWS) agg1, MAX(t1.YEAR) agg2
FROM CARS t0
INNER JOIN SHOWS t1
  ON (t1.CARID = t0.CARID)
GROUP BY t0.CARID
```

Comment: The query you gave should not generate the SQL that you gave.

Comment: Oh yeah I changed the original table names and accidentally removed the spaces. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```
from x in CARS
from y in SHOWS
    .Where(y=>y.CARID == x.CARID)
group y by x.CARS into g
select new { CARID = g.Key, agg1 = g.Max(z=>z.WINDOWS), agg2=g.Max(z=>z.YEAR) }
```

or if you have a navigation property set up from cars to shows, then:

```
var result=CARS.Select(c=>new {
  CARID=c.CARID, 
  agg1=c.Shows.Max(s=>s.WINDOWS), 
  agg2=c.Shows.Max(s=>s.YEAR)});
```